# How to save uipickerview data for core data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

There is one uipickerview in a single view application.
The user selects a name by click on a uibutton.

To be more specific

- there is one uibutton named as city
- the user clicks on the button and the uipickerview appears at the bottom and the user selects one name so the uipickerview disappears and the value is displayed in the uibutton named as city.

So, how to get the data from the uipickerview for coredata in iOS Swift application?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift

Answer (score 0):

You can set your class as picker view delegate throught delegate property on picker view. Your class should conform to the UIPickerViewDelegate protocol, and implement method

```
optional func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
```

you got `row` parametr here and you can just pick up the related data. Then you can easily save it to core data.